# Probability of winning first, second or third in a contest with 100 contestants

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**The Question**

Suppose that 100 people enter a contest and that different
winners are selected at random for first, second, and third
prizes. What is the probability that Michelle wins one of
these prizes if she is one of the contestants?

**My Work**

Our sample space is all the possible permutations of first second and third out of 100 contestants. Therefore $|S| = P(100,3)$

There are three possible scenarios where Michelle wins a prize. Therefore the probability that she wins a prize is $\frac{3}{P(100,3)}$

**My Question**

My book gave the answer $\frac{3}{100}$ why is the sample space only 100? This makes no sense to me. A sample size is all the possible outcomes of an experiment. The experiment was awarding first second and third too 100 contestants. $P(100,3)$ possible outcomes, right? Was my book wrong?

Comment: With your description of the sample space, there aren't just three possible scenarios where Michelle wins a prize: when Michelle wins first or second or third, there are $P(99,2)$ ways to fill the other two spots in the top three.  So the probability is $3 P(99,2)/P(100,3)=3\cdot 99 \cdot 98 / (100 \cdot 99 \cdot 98)$, or $3/100$.

Comment: Not much of a contest is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are more than $3$ scenarios in which Michelle wins a prize.  She can win first prize in $\frac{99\cdot 98}{2}$ since you have to include in you scenario the results of the other two picks, if you are going to divide by $\binom{100}{3}$.  She can win second or third prize in the same number of ways.

So her chances of winning turn out to be 
$$\frac{\left(\frac{3\cdot 99 \cdot 98}{3!}\right)}{ \left(\frac{100\cdot 99 \cdot 98}{3!}\right)}=\frac{3}{100}
$$

Comment: The left-hand expression has an error.

Answer (score 2):

There are $100$ people in the contest, $3$ are selected at random (assume without bias).  Michelle will either be one of these three, or not.

*Favoured Space:* Michelle is one of 3 people chosen.

*Total Space:* Michelle is one of 100 people.

Hence the probability is $3/100$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way: Michelle is equally likely to be ranked first, second, third, ..., ninety-ninth, one hundredth. Now what's the probability that she's ranked first, second, or third?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count all of the possible combinations, it should reduce to $0.03$, but it's not necessary.

The number of outcomes where Michelle is one of the winners is

$$\frac{99 \choose 2}{100 \choose 3} = \frac{\frac{99 \cdot 98}{2}}{\frac{100 \cdot 99 \cdot 98}{3 \cdot 2}} = \frac{3}{100}.$$